# How to turn on git syntax highlighting on vim on a Mac

Tags: macos, git, vim

I just recently switched over to Mac. On windows I was using git through the msysgit project. When doing a `git rebase -i` I'm used to get a nice syntax highlighting in `vim`. I'm missing it badly now that I'm on Mac. How can I get it back?

Comment: Is it syntax highlighted when you do outside of vim?

Comment: the colors for the `git log` etc do work, yes. I have `git config --global color.ui true`

Comment: Did you not copy your previous Vim config over?

Comment: `msysgit`seemed to abstract all those difficulties away from the end user. All the highlighting worked just out of the box so until my first interactive rebase on my new MacBook I didn't even know that something like a vim config does even exist :)

Comment: as a side note, may i introduce you to vim-fugitive ? https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive (see the screencasts on vimcast.org http://vimcasts.org/episodes/fugitive-vim---a-complement-to-command-line-git/)

Comment: Need to check it out :)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

I just figured out all I need is to create a `~/.vimrc` file with a line that reads

```
syntax on
```

Comment: you should mark your answer as correct. It helped me for sure!

Answer (score 2):

For me the issue was git was using "vi" instead of "vim". Adding this to my .bashrc fixed it:

```
export EDITOR=vim
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to set up an `autocmd` in your `.vimrc` to recognise the appropriate file as a `rebase -i` temporary:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead git-rebase-todo setf gitrebase
```

Then you just need to use a syntax file `~/.vim/syntax/gitrebase.vim` and put in whatever highlighting commands match your preferences such as the one supplied with recents vims:
https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/syntax/gitrebase.vim

Comment: I created the `.vimrc`at `~/` with the line that you postet and also created the `gitrebase.vim` file at `~/.vim/syntax/` with the content from that link. Then I reopened the terminal and tried it. It doesn't work. Anything I might be missing?

Comment: Ok, I just figured out all I need is that `.vimrc` file with a line that reads `syntax on`